# Flutter prevent listview showing in new line

Tags: flutter, listview, newline

I want to show my listview **in same line one after another** but listview showing every item in every new line. How can I prevent to show in new line. So that **it shows like paragraph**

```
ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount:
      controller.page.value.data.ayahs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         return Text(controller.page.value.data.ayahas[index].name);
     })
```

Please look at this photo. I want to show text like this one after another instead of new line
[image: Listview Text one after another]

Comment: could you put a picture of the problem please??

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Wrap` widget. For example, like this.

```
final List<String> ayahs = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'very', 'very', 'very', 'very', 'very', 'very', 'very', 'very', 'very', 'very', 'long', 'text'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: ayahs
          .map((element) => Text(element))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using List generator inside a grid view and provide crossAxisCount same as the length of the list to get list items in a row.

```
GridView.count(
   crossAxisCount: controller.page.value.data.ayahs.length,
   children: List.generate(controller.page.value.data.ayahs.length, (index) {
       return GridTile(
           child: Text(controller.page.value.data.ayahas.name)
       );
   }),
),
```